# Run LinqPad v5 in x86 mode

Tags: visual-foxpro, linqpad

Is there a way to force LinqPad version 5.1 to run in x86 mode?  I think I found a way to do it in the past but I have searched for several hours on the internet and cannot find it.

Specially what I want to be able to do is execute Vfp OleDb commands but it is giving me an error that `VFPOLEDB.1 provider is not registered on the local machine`.  I assume this is because I am running in AnyCPU mode (the LinqPad web site says AnyCPU defaults to x64.  The crazy thing about it is that I have a saved query for this so it seems like I had to have been able to do it in the past.

Comment: Why not download the x86 version of LINQPad for this then? At least the beta - http://www.linqpad.net/download.aspx#beta - is available in both AnyCPU and x86 versions. Not sure about the release-versions.

Comment: I thought about that but I feel like there is a way to switch to x86 since I was running the saved query in the past.  The other possibility I guess is that a more recent version of LinqPad 5 changed the AnyCPU default from x86 to x64.  Thanks for your response.

Comment: It would be nice it to have it directly on a single instance like choosing C# program/C# statements with Ctrl+N. Anyway I spent my votes on bringing LinqPad to OS X with Mono support :)

Comment: Cetin: Yes, that would be nice, but expensive to implement in LINQPad because the debugger would have to run in a separate process, with all communication between LINQPad and the debugger done over IPC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I have is the x86 version as the default. I have both versions on my taskbar.
That is true that the reason is you are running anyCPU version on a 64 bits machine.